# Is there a closed-form expression for this sum in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Tags: summation, closed-form

We have the sum

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n {i (i^m - (i - 1)^m)}$$

where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers. WolframAlpha will evaluate the sum for specific values of $m$, but returns no result when $m$ is left as a variable. I've tried to find a pattern in the results for specific values of $m$, with limited success. The first few expressions are:

1. $\frac{1}{ 2} n   (n + 1)$
2. $\frac{1}{ 6} n   (n + 1) (4 n - 1)$
3. $\frac{1}{ 4} n^2 (n + 1) (3 n - 1)$
4. $\frac{1}{30} n   (n + 1) (24 n^3 - 9 n^2 - n + 1)$
5. $\frac{1}{12} n^2 (n + 1) (10 n^3 - 4 n^2 - n + 1)$
6. $\frac{1}{42} n   (n + 1) (36 n^5 - 15 n^4 - 6 n^3 + 6 n^2 +   n - 1)$
7. $\frac{1}{24} n^2 (n + 1) (21 n^5 -  9 n^4 - 5 n^3 + 5 n^2 + 2 n - 2)$
8. $\frac{1}{90} n   (n + 1) (80 n^7 - 35 n^6 - 25 n^5 + 25 n^4 + 17 n^3 - 17 n^2 - 3 n + 3)$
9. $\frac{1}{20} n^2 (n + 1) (18 n^7 -  8 n^6 -  7 n^5 +  7 n^4 +  7 n^3 -  7 n^2 - 3 n + 3)$

Except for the $m = 1$ case, which stands on its own, the results seem to come in pairs. The even-$m$ case is in the form [reciprocal of a number] $× n × (n + 1) ×$ [polynomial of degree $m - 1$]. The odd-$m$ case immediately following that is in the form [reciprocal of a smaller number] $× n^2 × (n + 1) ×$ [polynomial of same degree but with generally smaller or equal coefficients]. Beyond that, I'm stumped.

Is there a closed-form expression for this sum in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^ni(i^m-(i-1)^m)&=\sum_{i=1}^ni^{m+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)^{m+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)^m\\
&=n^{m+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^m.\end{align*}$$
Now, there is a [well-known formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i^m$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: I'm not seeing how the first expression in your answer is true. It seems like the right side is not equal to the left side. Am I missing something?

Comment: It also looks like Faulhaber's formula is for $\sum_{i = 1}^n i^m$, not $\sum_{i = 0}^{n  -1} i^m$.

Comment: @Lawton - $i = (i-1) +1$, but there is a sign error. The final sum should also be subtracted. As for Faulhaber's formula, just add $0$ to it to cover the $i = 0$ term (when $m \ne 0$), and apply the formula with $n$ replaced by $n-1$.